# Phonegap 3: phonegap install ios - error: no platforms added to this project

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator

I created a new phonegap 3 project

> phonegap create my-app
>
> cd my-app

Then I was trying to install to ios

> phonegap install ios

```
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
[phonegap] trying to install app onto emulator
 [warning] missing ios-sim
 [warning] install ios-sim from http://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim
   [error] No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>`.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) As you can see from the warning you need to install ios-sim.

Follow the instructions from [github.com/phonegap/ios-sim](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim)

*Brew install* didn't work for me, so I built and installed ios-sim from the source root

```
git clone git://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim.git
cd ios-sim
rake install prefix=/usr/local/
```

2) You need to build the project for dedicated platform before install it.

Firstly

```
phonegap build ios
```

Secondly

```
phonegap install ios
```

Comment: After I built the iOS project, how I update it if I made some changes in the Phonegap app?

Comment: 1) I use grunt to build html5 app. 2) Then I use .sh script to update www folder inside of iOS project and call 'phonegap build ios'. 3) I open ios project in xcode and execute in on device. 
Did I answer yo your question @ov1d1u?